# How can i pass a modified image from a tool window to the main window?

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv

In the main window i can open, save or create an image. If i modify this image in a second window, how can i send the result in the main window when i close the second windows?

```
import sys
import cv2


from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
```

This is the second windows where i pass the image loaded in the main window and i made some modification.

```
class toolWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(toolWindows, self).__init__()
        self._image = image
        self._result = None
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        modifyImage = QtWidgets.QAction('&modifyTheImage', self)
        modifyImage.setShortcut('Ctrl+M')
        modifyImage.setStatusTip('modify the image image')
        modifyImage.triggered.connect(self.doSomething)

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&modify')
        fileMenu.addAction(modifyImage)
        self.show()

    def doSomething(self):
        self._result = cv2.Canny(self._image,100,200)
        cv2.imshow('doSomething',self._result)
        return self._result

    def getResult(self):
        return self._result
```

this is the main windows

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mainWindowImageSource = None
        self.mainWindowImageResult = None
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        LoadImage = QtWidgets.QAction('&LoadImage', self)
        LoadImage.setShortcut('Ctrl+L')
        LoadImage.setStatusTip('Load an image')
        LoadImage.triggered.connect(self.loadImage)

        toolWin = QtWidgets.QAction('&tool', self)
        toolWin.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        toolWin.setStatusTip('open the tool win')
        toolWin.triggered.connect(self.openToolWindow)

        checkResult = QtWidgets.QAction('&Check', self)
        checkResult.setShortcut('Ctrl+K')
        checkResult.setStatusTip('check that tool win pass the image on close')
        checkResult.triggered.connect(self.checkResultImage)

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(LoadImage)
        fileMenu.addAction(toolWin)
        fileMenu.addAction(checkResult)
        self.show()

    def loadImage(self):
        fileName, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', 'C:\\', "Image Files (*.jpg)")
        if fileName:
            self.mainWindowImageSource = cv2.imread(fileName, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        else:
            print('Invalid Image')

    def openToolWindow(self):
        self.tw = toolWindows(self.mainWindowImageSource)
        self.tw.show()
        self.mainWindowImageResult = self.tw.getResult()


    def checkResultImage(self):
        print("ol")
        cv2.imshow('test', self.mainWindowImageResult)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()



##### APP MAIN ####
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = mainWindow()
# this start a loop till exit
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution accordingly with varius post i found.
To get a result from the second windows the simplest way is probably to use a QDialog.

in the main windows i change the code in this way:

```
    def openToolWindow(self):
        self.tw = toolWindows(self.mainWindowImageSource)
        self.tw.show()
        check = True
        if self.tw.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        self.mainWindowImageResult = self.tw.getResult()
        cv2.imshow('test', self.mainWindowImageResult)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this way wheh it open the second windows (the tool windows), the main wait for the accept button and take the result with getResult() -a function that simply return the image-